# Marshaling a C++ two-dimensional fixed length char array as a structure member

Tags: c#, c++, struct, multidimensional-array, marshalling

I am trying to call an unmanaged C++ function, that has a structure as an input parameter.
The structure is defined in the header file like this:

```
struct MyStruct
{
int     siOrder;
char     aaszNames[6][25];
int     siId[6];
int     siTones[6];        
};
```

I tried to declare the managed struct as following:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct MyStruct {

public int siOrder;

[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=150)]
public string aaszNames;

[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=6, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.I4)]
public int[] siId;

[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=6, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.I4)]
public int[] siTones;
}
```

But without any success. I am guessing that the marshaling fails, since the aaszNames is actually an array of six 25 long null-terminating strings.
I tried declaring aaszNames as

```
 [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=150)]
 public char[] aaszNames;
```

filling the array with nulls where necessary. But, again, nothing.

Is there something I am missing? What am I dong wrong? What is the best way to marshal this 2-D char array?

Any hints, please.

Comment: Does not look at all like C++...

Comment: He wants to call a C++ function from C#

Comment: I have added a C# tag to hopefully make it clearer as to what is meant. I also thought this was a pure C++ question until I got to the code.

Comment: I think Matthieu says your unmanaged code is rather C-like and suggests using std::string or something like that in C++?

Comment: yes, i agree it's rather C-like, but this is a third party dll, with a poor documentation referring to it as C++ dll...
Cannot really do anything to change this dll.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am having a similar issue, can't get marshalasattribute to work with values like your siId or siTones

Comment: @TTheot Do you remember the solution of the above :)

Answer (score 7):

Try using multiple C# structs:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct MyStruct_Name
{
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 25)]
    public string name;
}

[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    public int siOrder;

    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public MyStruct_Name aaszNames;

    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int[] siId;

    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int[] siTones;
}
```

This is how I've been passing arrays of C-style strings around.

Don't forget to create the contents of aaszNames!  The marshaller hates null references.

```
MyStruct foo = new MyStruct();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    foo.aaszNames[i] = new MyStruct_Name();
    foo.aaszNames[i].name = "";
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=150)]
 public char[] aaszNames;
```

That marshalling type looks well. Probably issue in function call, or bad memory allocation/

Comment: The function I am calling, has one more structure as a parameter, with which I have no problem. What exactly do you mean with bad memory allocation?

Comment: 1. How you alloc a memory for your struct?
2. Best way for marshal struct as input function parameter is pointer(IntPtr).

Typical example:
IntPtr strPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(StructType)));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct,strPtr);
Foo(strPtr);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(strPtr);

Comment: I really do not alloc memory manually. I am aware of that example, but since I manage to successfully pass the other (simpler) struct as input parameter in the same function, and in several others, I thought that leaving this to .NET would also work.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a small c-program to check the byte size of the C-structure.
Then I would go with the other suggestion to extract the data field by field.
From a C standpoint the /0 is treated as normal character included in the 6 bytes whereas C# would use a length of 5 and have the /0 hidden.

Answer (score -3):

```
char aaszNames[6][25];
```

char of C++ Type is 8 bits~

but char of  C# Type is Unicode ,(16 bits) !

so char of C++ Type <-> byte of C# type