# Marshal a C char[][] array to C#

Tags: c#, c++, c, interop, marshalling

I have looked and looked and tried everything I can think of or have found suggested. I'm still not having any luck getting the data I need.

I'm using a third party DLL, which I believe is written in C. I need to access the functions from this DLL in C#. For the most part, I have this working, except for one function.  The function I'm having problems with has the following header:

```
uint queryNumOfServers(USHORT *NumOfServers, char ServerNames[8][16]);
```

I have the following declared in my C# application

```
[DllImport("client.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi]
public static extern uint queryNumOfServers(ref short numberofServer, StringBuilder serverNames);
```

I call this as follows:

```
StringBuilder serverNames = new StringBuilder(128);
short numServers = -1;
queryNumberOfServers(ref numServers, serverNames);
```

The problem is, while numberOfServers come back equal to 4, I only get one name in serverNames. I have tested the above C function in a small C program. I get back numberOfServer = 4 but I also get 4 names back.

---

I have tried the following with no success:

```
[DllImport("client.dll", CharSet=charSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern uint queryNumOfServers(ref short numberOfServer,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string serverNames);
```

Called this with

```
string serverNames = new string('\0', 128);
queryNumOfServers(ref numServers, serverNames);
```

There is no change to serverNames with this option.

---

The development environment is Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much searching and hair pulling, this was the solution that worked for me.

Declared the function header in my C# application as:

```
[DllImport("client.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern uint queryNumOfServers(ref short numberOfServers, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[,] serverNames);
```

Then called as follows:

```
byte[,] serverNames = new byte[8,16];
short numServers = -1;
queryNumberOfServers(ref numServers, serverNames);
```

This returns a double index byte array. From here I used Buffer.BlockCopy() and Encoding.UTF8.GetString() to convert my byte array into a array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

I would use  `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential...]` and `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr...]`.

Here are two good examples:

[Marshalling a C 2-Dimensional fixed length char array](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1618999-8448-46ef-9788-4b18a62d25ea/marshaling-a-c-twodimensional-fixed-length-char-array-as-a-structure-member)

[Marshaling a C++ two-dimensional fixed length char array as a structure member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266613/marshaling-a-c-two-dimensional-fixed-length-char-array-as-a-structure-member)

Comment: I'm have attempted to follow the instruction, but all I get is an TypeLoadException. Given that the function I'm attempting to call is looking for a double char array, I'm very unclear how this will work.