# Marshaling a C++ Struct with fixed size 2D char array from C#

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I have a c++ DLL that have one public function that accepts structure pointer.
I am using this DLL into C# (VS 2010, Build Type x86, Allow unsafe Code).

The structure which I need to marshal is having one more structure as member parameter and this member parameter structure need to have C++ like 2D char array of fixed size. I have implemented this structure as suggested by Stack Overflow and MSDN forum links as mentioned below :

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1618999-8448-46ef-9788-4b18a62d25ea/marshaling-a-c-twodimensional-fixed-length-char-array-as-a-structure-member
and
[Marshaling a C++ two-dimensional fixed length char array as a structure member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266613/marshaling-a-c-two-dimensional-fixed-length-char-array-as-a-structure-member).

Finally I am using an `Intptr` variable `xyz` and using `AllocHglobal(Marshal.Sizeof(abc))` to allocate memory and `Marshal.StructtoPointer(abc, xyz, false)` and then passing `xyz` in the C++ dll function call and I am getting an exception inside this function from C++ when I am trying to do a `memset` on the 2D `char[][] struct` ..

Exception is "Attempting to read write a protected memory".   Apart from this struct, everything is fine.  Please suggest any work around.

Comment: go through http://stackoverflow.com/q/21059950/3110262 I am sure u will get some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was the improper allocation of IntPtr . I was using Marshal.Sizeof(abc) instead of that I should use sizeof(STRUCTURE) . By doing this change I am successfully getting the struct parameter in C++ .